Iterate through Datepicker dates and add aria-selected='true' to the currently selected date with .ui-state-active
I have multiple date pickers on a page and I'm trying to iterate through the dates to find the currently selected date and add aria-selected='true' to the currently selected date with the class of.ui-state-active. First though, I want to loop through and remove the aria-selected='true' from all others, so only the selected date has the aria-selected value. I have created an OnSelect function to iterate the dates looking for the selected date.
Maybe I'm not using the correct event. Any help would be awesome. Thanks


$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("a .ui-state-default").each(function() {
        //Remove aria-selected from all existing dates to reset
        $(this).removeAttr('aria-selected');
        // Look for the selected date using class ui-state-active
        if ($(this).hasClass(".ui-state-active")) {
          // Add aria-selected='true' to the current selected date
          $(this).attr('aria-selected', true);
        }
      });
      console.log("Selected date:", dateText);
    }
  });
});
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https:////code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>


</body>

</html>



Date Picker on input field:  

Does your code produces any errors? If so a minimal, reproducible example would be nice so we can see whats wrong.

There aren't any errors I can see, It's either not finding the current selected item, or I'm calling it wrong. I will try and get a working example in a bit.

I have added a working example, Thanks
